# How to find not matching records in Generic List in C#

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list, except

I have two Generic List object, I want to get records which are not matching in second Generic list object. Below is my code. But it returning all records.

I want to ignore matching record in first list.

```
public class CuratedIncludeUid
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string uid { get; set; }
    }

List<CuratedIncludeUid> newUids = new List<CuratedIncludeUid>();
            newUids.Add(new CuratedIncludeUid { type = "series", uid = "600" });

            List<CuratedIncludeUid> liExistingUids = new List<CuratedIncludeUid>();
            liExistingUids.Add(new CuratedIncludeUid { type = "series", uid = "600" });
            liExistingUids.Add(new CuratedIncludeUid { type = "series", uid = "200" });

            var ied = liExistingUids.Except(newUids).ToList(); ;
            foreach (var row in ied)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Uid:" + row.uid + "type:" + row.type);
            }
            Console.Read();

I am getting Output as below 
Uid:600type:series
Uid:200type:series

**My expected output as below
Uid:200type:series**
```

Comment: Can you include the code for `CuratedIncludeUid`?

Comment: @CaTs Included code

Comment: You are comparing different objects. You need to use a custom comparer. You can read details with sample here: https://cetinbasoz.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/linq-query-operators-–-part-vi/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Either, you can implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or `IEqualityComparer`, or you can also do the following:

With [**All**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var ied = liExistingUids.Except(newUids).ToList();
liExistingUids
  .Where(x => newUids.All(y => y.type != x.type && y.series != x.series))
  .ToList();
```

With [**Any**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
liExistingUids
  .Where(x => !newUids.Any(y => y.type == x.type && y.series == x.series))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Helps me with Any() method

Comment: When overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` it is crucial that the object be read-only or, at least, the hash code doesn't change with the properties/fields do.

Answer (score 1):

Either override [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`GetHashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
public class CuratedIncludeUid
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }

    protected bool Equals(CuratedIncludeUid other)
    {
        return string.Equals(type, other.type) && string.Equals(uid, other.uid);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        return Equals((CuratedIncludeUid) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((type != null ? type.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ (uid != null ? uid.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or passing an [`IEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) to [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__)

```
public class CuratedIncludeUidEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<CuratedIncludeUid>
{
    public bool Equals(CuratedIncludeUid x, CuratedIncludeUid y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        return string.Equals(x.type, y.type) && string.Equals(x.uid, y.uid);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CuratedIncludeUid obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((obj.type != null ? obj.type.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ (obj.uid != null ? obj.uid.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }
}
```

```
var ied = liExistingUids.Except(newUids, new CuratedIncludeUidEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: When overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` it is crucial that the object be read-only or, at least, the hash code doesn't change with the properties/fields do.